# Exception in HTML 5 audio tag in android

Tags: android, html, cordova

My eclipse android emulator throws error when I run the html5 audio tag  to play a mp3 file.
My code is

```
 <audio controls="controls" autoplay >
<source src= "audios/test.mp3" />
</audio>
```

and here is my error in eclipse console window is

> error (1, -2147483648)

.

I could not find a solution. The code works in chrome. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Vinod I tried the same, but the android emulator don´t support until now Audio/Video reproduction when you embbed the media into the audio tag.